# Work days calculate with Apps Script, getDay and getDate deprecated

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I have to create a script for my Google Sheet that it return me a work days dates array.

This is my code:

```
function getWorkingDays(startDate, endDate) 
{
  var days = [];
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (currentDate <= endDate) 
  {
    var dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay();
    if (dayOfWeek !== 5 && dayOfWeek !== 6)
    {
      days.push(new Date(currentDate));
    }
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return days;
}
```

It works very well for my goal but I read that getDay(), getDate() and setDate() are deprecated.

How can I replace them?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect in your function `getWorkingDays`? By the way, Can I ask you about the detail of `but I read that getDay(), getDate() and setDate() are deprecated.`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `@Tanaike I have two dates as input:`, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: `getDate()` is a deprecated method in java.  Google app script uses javascript.  There is still only Date object.  There is no Calendar object.

Comment: @Tanaike I have two input dates:

startDate=20/02/2023
endDate= 27/02/2023

I expect that the fuction return me an array which contains the work day dates beteween two input dates: 

Output: 

days=[20/02/2023, 21/02/2023, 22/02/2023, 23/02/2023, 24/02/2023, 27/02/2023].

for details about deprecated method: 

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: You need to explain where the DateField comes from.  As noted in your link "This class is only used by the Contacts service, and dates used elsewhere in App Script use JavaScript's standard Date object."  Google Sheets uses Date objects.

Comment: You are right! I didn't read the alert. Google Sheet uses the standard Date objects which is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain where the DateField comes from. As noted in your link "This class is only used by the Contacts service, and dates used elsewhere in App Script use JavaScript's standard Date object." Google Sheets uses Date objects. –
TheWizEd